# Como fixar caixa de busca no menu?

Tags: html, css

Queria saber como fixa caixa de busca no menu !!

O designe do menu com a caixa :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código:

```css
.nav{
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
 background-color:#4682B4;    
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:1.000em;
 color:#fff;
    float:left;
}

.menu{
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 88%;
 margin-left:11.23046875%;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    min-width: 200px;
 z-index:99;
}

.nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav ul li a, visited{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.813em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
 background-color: #222;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

.img-menu{
 display:none; 
}

/*-----------Config. da caixa de pesquisa------------*/

.search{
 width:130px;
 height:33px;
 top:-2px;
 right:-2px;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
 background:#222;
 color:#FFF;
 position:relative; 
 font-size:16px;
}

.btn-busca{
 width:33px;
 height:35px;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
 background:#FF7F00;
 cursor:pointer;
 top:2px;
 left:-4px;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
 <div class="img-menu"><img src="img/icn-menu.png"/></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Games</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Gameplays</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trailers</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Downloads</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Games</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Editor de Imagens</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Editor de Áudio e Vídeo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Segurança</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sistemas Oprecionais</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Os Mais Baixados</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Android</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">IOS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Windows Phone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li> <a href="#">Internet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Redes Socias</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Diversão</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Filmes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Animes/desenhos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Memes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Histórias bisarras</a>
                    </li>
             </ul>
                <li> <a href="#">TI</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Progamção</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorias</a>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
 </div> 

<form class="searchbox" action="busca.html" method="get">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
    <button class="btn-busca"><img src="img/tb-lupa.png"/></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em seu caso, você poderia simplesmente colocar o seu form dentro de um `li` e alinhar o mesmo a direita.

Para isso você pode criar um classe e alinhar a direita, desta forma:

```
li.right { float:right; }
```

Feito isso, basta adicionar sua busca dentro do `li`, desta forma:

```
 <li class="right">              
     <form class="searchbox" action="busca.html" method="get">
         <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
         <button class="btn-busca"><img src="img/tb-lupa.png"/></button>
     </form>
 </li>
```

Seu código completo ficará assim:

```css
.nav{
    width:100%;
    height:42px;
 background-color:#4682B4;    
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:1.000em;
 color:#fff;
    float:left;
}

.menu{
 margin: 0 auto;
    width: 88%;
 margin-left:11.23046875%;
    text-align: left;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
    min-width: 200px;
 z-index:99;
}

.nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul li:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav ul li a, visited{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.813em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
 background-color: #222;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
}

.img-menu{
 display:none; 
}

/*-----------Config. da caixa de pesquisa------------*/

.search{
 width:130px;
 height:33px;
 top:-2px;
 right:-2px;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
 background:#222;
 color:#FFF;
 position:relative; 
 font-size:16px;
}

.btn-busca{
 width:33px;
 height:35px;
 outline:none;
 border:none;
 background:#FF7F00;
 cursor:pointer;
 top:2px;
 left:-4px;
 position:relative;
}
li.right { float:right; }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
 <div class="img-menu"><img src="img/icn-menu.png"/></div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Games</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Gameplays</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Reviews</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Trailers</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Downloads</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Games</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Editor de Imagens</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Editor de Áudio e Vídeo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Segurança</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sistemas Oprecionais</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Os Mais Baixados</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Mobile</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Android</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">IOS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Windows Phone</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li> <a href="#">Internet</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Redes Socias</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dicas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">Diversão</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Filmes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Animes/desenhos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Memes</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Histórias bisarras</a>
                    </li>
             </ul>
                <li> <a href="#">TI</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Progamção</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorias</a>
                    </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
                        <li class="right">
                            
<form class="searchbox" action="busca.html" method="get">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Buscar...">
    <button class="btn-busca"><img src="img/tb-lupa.png"/></button>
</form>
    </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
 </div>
```

[Veja um Exemplo em tela cheia](https://jsfiddle.net/randrade/p399Lyev/embedded/result/)

Comment: valeu mesmo. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Os elementos `div` e `form` possuem a propriedade CSS `display: block` por padrão do browser.

Segue uma [`definição`](http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/display.html) dessa propriedade:

> O elemento de bloco sempre começa em uma nova linha e se expande pra esquerda e direita o tanto quanto for possível

No entanto, existem várias maneiras de fazer com que os elementos fiquem lado a lado.

## 1. float:left

Segue um exemplo da propriedade [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) com valor `left` (é possível também utilizar right para alinhar à direita):

```css
div {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>elemento 1</div>
<div>elemento 2</div>
```

## 2. display: inline-block

Segue um exemplo utilizando a propriedade [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) com valor `inline-block`:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div>elemento 1</div>
<div>elemento 2</div>
```

## 3. display: flex

Essa opção merece um estudo aprofundado. É uma novidade do CSS3 com um potencial enorme para organização dos elementos. Recomendo a leitura do seguinte material para maior aprendizado: [`A Complete Guide to Flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>elemento 1</div>
  <div>elemento 2</div>
</div>
```